# How to have a vector of integers in Java

Tags: java, vector, int

im trying to get a vector of integers by using the following:

```
Vector<int> vec =new Vector<int>();
```

but I get an error:

> Syntax error on token "int", Dimensions expected after this token

I'm aware that Vector only accepts objects,

is there a simple way of having a vector of integers without creating an object that just stores an int?

Thanks

Comment: `Vector<Integer>`

Comment: ITT:  why C# is better than java

Comment: @SamIam Because of years of hindsight.

Comment: An old joke: Why do Java programmers wear glasses? Because they don't C#.

Comment: @clairharrison Don't use a Vector in Java to start with. I guess it can work, especially if you know C/C++. It is standard to use a `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` in Java.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `Vector<Integer>`.

Autoboxing will allow you to add `Integer`s as if they are `int`s.

For example:

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>(); //Diamonds are allowed in 7+
vector.add(5);
```

Also, you forgot to mention an instance name for your vector.

Answer (score 3):

> is there a simple way of having a vector of integers without creating an object that just stores an int?

There already is such a type, it's called [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html). It's the [boxed type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Boxing) of the [primitive type `int`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). But because of the way that [generics in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) are implemented, they do not support type parameters that are primitives. Instead, for primitives, you must use the boxed type. So in your case

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<Integer>();
```

You can leverage the fact that [primitives are auto boxed/unboxed to/from their boxed type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to write code like

```
vector.add(42);
```

and

```
int answer = vector.get(42);
```

The compiler will convert these to the appropriate boxing and unboxing operations.

Comment: Why are you all keep posting one same answer?

Comment: He got his answer in first comment. Its ridiculous to post all these same answers.

Comment: The [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239841/how-to-have-a-vector-of-integers-in-java/17239907?noredirect=1#comment24980668_17239841) you're referring to explains nothing; it's a good *comment* but not a good *answer*. The actual answers were posted at approximately the same time and have varying degrees of elaboration on the issues involved.

Answer (score 1):

The formal parameter in generics must be an object and not a primitive. Use the `Integer` wrapper like so: `Vector<Integer>`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Integer` Object. Use `Vector<Integer>`

```
Vector<Integer>=new Vector<Integer>();
```